# Can't catch unsuccessful parsing events when using requests to parse a list of image urls python3

Tags: python-3.x, url, python-requests, try-catch

**Hi I am using the following function to parse a list of img reference urls.** The reference urls are in format "https://......strings/"; the parsed urls are in format "http://..../img.jpg".

**Input**: a text file, each line is a reference url

**Expected output**: a list of parsed urls.

**Parsing Rules**:

For each input url, `requests` parse it to html.  `html.url` will either return 1) the original url or 2) a successfully parsed url. If the original url is returned, use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the img url inside the html. If somehow the extraction fails, resume original url. Then try the whole process again until maximum `try_num` is reached or success.

**Actual behavior**:

```
success: http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/large/005ZD4gwgw1fa6u080sdlj30ku112n4b.jpg
success: http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/005ZD4gwgw1fa6tzfpvkwj305t058t8o.jpg
success: https://weibo.cn/mblog/oripic?id=EjvpZdb4y&u=005ZD4gwgw1fa6tzvk95tg30n20cqqva&rl=1
```

**As you can see, even with unsuccessful parsing (3rd), the function outputs "success" without any of the error message I put. I have tried manually parsing those reference urls and tested "html.url == imgref"; they are good. So it somehow happens when I feed a list of urls to it. I am really not sure where it went wrong. Seems all `try..except` blocks did not catch any exception.**

Apologize ahead if I have made some very stupid mistakes and for the ambiguous title. I really don't know where the problem is so I can't find a good tile.

Thank you all.

```
 def decode_imgurl(imgref,cookie):
    connection_timeout = 90
    try_num = 1
    imgurl = imgref

    start_time = time.time()
    while imgurl == imgref:
        while True:
            try:
                html = requests.get(imgref,cookies=cookie, timeout=60)
                break
            except Exception:
                if time.time() > start_time + connection_timeout:
                    raise Exception('Unable to get connection %s after %s seconds of ConnectionErrors' \
                            % (imgref, self.connection_timeout))
                else:
                    time.sleep(1)

        if html.url == imgref:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content,"lxml")
            try:
                imgurl = soup.findAll("a",href=re.compile(r'^http://',re.I))[0]['href']
            except IndexError: # happens with continuous requests in short time
                print("requests too fast")
                imgurl = imgref
                time.sleep(1)
        else:
            imgurl = html.url

        try_num += 1

        if try_num > 10:
            print("fail to parse. Please parse manually")
            return ""

    print("success: %s" % imgurl)
    return imgurl

from config import cookie # import cookie file
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            parsed_url = decode_imgurl(line.strip(), cookie)
            print(parsed_url)
```

Comment: I also tested each single unsuccessful url running with the function. They are all parsed successfully when parsed alone. So I think the parsing problem is of too frequently requesting and I understand. My question is really why the function prints "sucess: imgurl" when clearly "imgurl = imgref" and the maximum try_num hasn't been reached.